# The natural language sentences generation

Tags: nlp, nltk

I'm looking for a way how to generate or synthesize natural language sentences. I need to write about 1000 sentences like following:

"Hi there! I would like to go for a walk around the city in the evening. Do not be shy, text me message"

or

"Whats up guys! I'm looking for a company for visiting museum of science. It is more enjoyable to visit it with somebody"

It is users' events. For example a user wants to visit some place, event, seek a company for outdoor or trip together.

I found just one way: write list of first, second and third part of a sentence and then randomly assemble whole sentence from parts. 
But I do not know, maybe there already is similar lists? Maybe there are another way or special techniques for solve my task?

Answer (score 1):

You can write possible sentences and use paraphrases to rephrase your sentences, [PPDB](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~ccb/ppdb/) is a great resource for that. [This](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~ccb/publications/sentential-paraphrasing-demo-paper.pdf) is a recent research paper on how to use machine translation system for this goal.

Comment: Tank you! It might be really useful!